# When using nodal analysis of a circuit involving CCCS, how do you know which currents are entering and which are leaving?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, ltspice, kirchhoffs-laws

I am trying to solve the following circuit:

[image]

I believe the answer I'm getting for \$i_b\$ is wrong because I put it into LTSpice and I'm getting that \$i_b = -3.63636\$

This is my LTSpice diagram:

[image]

I found \$i_b = 1\$mA by doing a loop voltage analysis on the left loop; for the voltage drop across the \$200\Omega\$ resistor I assumed that it would be \$i_b + 29i_b\$, which works out to be a nice number and in fact all of the numbers are nice in this case--usually when the numbers are nice, you know you're doing it right.

[image]

At this point, I'm not sure if I incorrectly modeled this in LTSpice, or if I incorrectly assumed which way the current was flowing.

Instead of giving me the answer directly, I would just like to know how to determine whether the current at a node is entering or leaving a branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node Analysis - current calculation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56936/node-analysis-current-calculation)

Comment: General answer without looking at your example: Leaving and entering is simply a matter of sign convention. If you know the relative polarity of the sources you can deduce current polarity. If not then plugging in what you know in a consistent manner will produce consistent results. The problems usually come from an inconsistent application of this basic concept.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The answer given in that question states that you can just "guess the current" and it will work out positive or negative, but in this case if I guess the opposite then I will get a voltage drop of 200*(28ib) at the 200 ohm resistor--vs 200*(30ib). This will change the answer... (I say this unconfidently because I don't know what my mistakes are).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Since I have a CCCS, won't the answer change, as I described in my previous comment?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your SPICE diagram, but: Why is 0.8 shown as Vib 0.8 (is that a dependent voltage) - are you using the 0.8 to control i1 in any way ?

Comment: No, I labelled it as Vib to reference it in the CCCS. I checked and it is multiplying the current through there by 29 in the CCCS. Mind you, I am very new to LTSpice (< 2 days).

Comment: It looks like your Spice simulation is wrong because I1 is an independent current source, not a CCCS.

Comment: @Null It is an 'F' device (\lib\sym\f.asy), but the instance name is 'I1'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your paper analysis is correct, but your LTspice simulation is incorrect. I get the same (incorrect) result as you if I use a gain of \$+29\$ for the F device (your \$I_1\$). But the gain should be \$-29\$ since \$i_b\$ flows from the negative to positive terminal of \$V_{\text{ib}}\$. Changing the gain gives you the correct result.

Circuit:

[image]

F device attributes:

[image]

Result:

[image]

If I change the gain to \$+29\$ the result is:

[image]

Note that the simulation result is \$v_y = v_{y1} - v_{y2} \approx 98\$V when using a gain of \$+29\$, which is clearly wrong.

The two simulations highlight the importance of maintaining consistency in the direction of currents. The problem statement defines \$i_b\$ and \$29i_b\$ as both flowing toward the middle "T" node. LTspice defines \$i_b\$ as flowing away from it since it defines the current through \$V_{\text{ib}}\$ as flowing from positive to negative terminal. That means you also have to define the CCCS \$29i_b\$ as flowing away from the middle "T" node. In the incorrect simulation (with gain of \$+29\$), \$29i_b\$ is still flowing toward the "T" node while \$i_b\$ is flowing away from it. The correct simulation defines them both as flowing away from the "T" node. Alternatively, you could just switch the direction of the "F" device and use a positive current gain -- it would then also be defined as flowing away from the "T" node.

Comment: Thank you very much for going to the length to find the mistake! I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. At least I learned something from this.

Comment: @Klik Happy to help.

Comment: I don't know if it's too late, but LTspice's currents are distributed in a grid, and their directions are chosen to start from top left, going right and downwards. This can be easily berified by pressing `Alt` and hovering the mouse over the *wires*, in any topology. It's just a matter of arbitrary choice for the programming part, the same as current through elements that are fixed at entering into one pin, and exiting at the other: a fixed reference from the solver's perspective.

Answer (score -1):

While doing these type of problems don't worry about current directions. First covert \$i_b\$ in terms of the principle node, then apply nodal analysis thereafter and find all the currents in the branch. Then you will know the direction of currents.